# How do I use the count of marital status for the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot made for a certain dataset (using completejourney). I used facet wrap and bar chart to compare age of people 65+ marital status by their income.

I got the code done but I want the x-axis to be the count of marital status under the certain income but I'm not sure what it is actually using. If it is using the count already how to I get a list of 1-... on the x-axis. [my code and ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzpk3.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Make sure to include your data because right now it looks like your data may be imported in the incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use geom_bar() instead of geom_col() and remove “y = income”. The layer geom_bar() counts automatically the frequency of x (= marital_status).

```
library(arules)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arules'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     abbreviate, write
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
data("IncomeESL")
IncomeESL |>
  drop_na() |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = `marital status`)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~income)
```

[image: Marital Status per Income Category]